# How to extract URL from JSON object's property?

Tags: json

Frontendmasters courses have an API endpoint that displays all the URLs for the videos which can be accessed if one is logged in. The endpoint returns a JSON object. The video URLs are in 'lessondata' in the property 'sourcebase'. How can I extract those URL's in a txt file?

[API endpoint](https://api.frontendmasters.com/v1/kabuki/courses/react)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of the JSON and include your existing code for calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript example:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(raw_json_data);
$.each( data.lessondata, function( key, value ) {
     // do here whatever you want with your URLs, e.g.
     console.log( value ); // prints URL
});
```

This assumes that **raw_json_data** is your object and that **lessondata** is its property, *i.e.* not nested deeper in a property of a property of the object.

In any case - this is enough to get you going. You provided barely any info, no code and no attempts of your own.

Comment: This is API endpoint link, and all the URLs of this course are available in  'lessondata' in the property 'sourcebase'. I want to retrieve those URLs
https://api.frontendmasters.com/v1/kabuki/courses/react